# Declaring additional classes in .aspx pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

I have a difficult time making this code to work

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Admin.Web.Booking
{
    public partial class Book
    {
        public partial class obj : Admin.Base.AdminBase
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Response.Write("test");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Page declaration look like

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master/Admin1.Master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="obj.aspx.cs" Inherits="Admin.Web.Booking.Book.obj" %>
```

Designer file looks like

```
namespace Admin.Web.Booking
{

    public partial class Book
    {

        public partial class obj
        {
        }
    }

}
```

I get an error: Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Admin.Web.Booking.Book.obj'.

Dont understand how can I make obj class be part of an Book class in Admin.Web.Booking namespace. Admin.Base.AdminBase extends System.UI.Page.

Comment: how can you write class inside class??

Comment: @ebramtharwat really ebram?

Comment: @ebramtharwat They are called `nested classes`.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? There is no need for a nested class in the code-behind file for an ASPX page that I can think of.

Comment: @Jason Evans if I have 20 pages in this namespaces, i would really want to make some order into one big class

Comment: @JasonEvans I know i can live without it, but I would really want to know why this does not work

Comment: Do you mean you want to put the code for all 20 pages into 1 single class file, as 20 nested classes inside of a main class?

Comment: @JasonEvans I want to have 1 ns, couple of classes and split 20 nested classes accordingly to parent classes

Comment: @Bobson I guess your solution would be ending up with 20 namespaces

Comment: @John - No, my solution would end up with 20 classes in one namespace, which is the standard way of doing it.

Comment: @Bobson Sure, but if I want to use nested classes you would not know how to solve this problem. Right?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's not possible.  It seems to interpret everything before the last `.` as part of the namespace.  Which goes back to the question of why nested classes are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would suggest is making the class `obj` inherit from `Page`.

```
namespace Admin.Web.Booking
{
    public partial class Book
    {    
        public partial class obj : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
        }
    }
}
```

and see what happens.

If that fails to work, then I think you should not use a nested class in this way. I can easily see this becoming overly complicated to maintain, especially as more pages are added to the project.

If you want to structure your code then I would use folders in your project:

- Folder: Booking
- Folder: Orders
- Folder: Tickets

Basically split your website into different domains/boundaries. Then place ASPX pages into those folders e.g.

```
namespace Booking {
    public partial class Booking : Page {}
}

namespace Orders {
    public partial class Orders : Page {}
}
```

Don't split the code using nested classes, I can really see that becoming a painful experience for you.

OK based on the comment below, my preference would be multiple namespaces rather then a nested class.

Namespaces logically separate code into related areas e.g. Admin, Booking, Tickets, etc. It will be easier to navigate the code if it's placed in separate namespaces, which can easily be viewed in the solution explorer. Having all the code in a couple of class files will result in code that is harder to follow, and will, over time, reduce productivity, increases coupling and will become viscous.

Comment: Admin.Base.AdminBase already extends System.Web.UI.Page. Not really sure why do you think it would be complicated to mantain?

Comment: Solution you have provided is a good one, and that is what I am using at the moment. But the question is to either multiply number of namespaces (!) or go with nested classes